# Is this the proper way to flush the C input stream?

Tags: c, flush, fflush

Well I been doing a lot of searching on google and on here about how to flush the input stream properly. All I hear is mixed arguments about how fflush() is undefined for the input stream, and some say just do it that way, and others just say don't do it, I haven't had much luck on finding a clear efficient/proper way of doing so, that the majority of people agree on.. I am quite new at programming so I don't know all the syntax/tricks of the language yet, so my question which way is the most efficient/proper solution to clearing the C input stream??

1. Use the `getchar()` twice before I try to receive more input?
2. Just use the `fflush()` function on the input?  or
3. This is how I thought I should do it.

   ```
   void clearInputBuf(void);  
   void clearInputBuf(void) 
   { 
         int garbageCollector; 
         while ((garbageCollector = getchar()) != '\n' && garbageCollector != EOF) 
         {}
   }
   ```

So, whenever I need to read a new scanf(), or use getchar() to pause the program I just call the clearInputBuf.. So what would be the best way out of the three solutions or is there a even better option?

Comment: It's not simple. That's why there are libraries like [GNU Readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to handle input, because it's quite difficult to do it using library functions.

Comment: Just a side note for anyone reading this as a solution!  There are other ways to get input more efficiently, but if your just learning this will most likely serve you well enough until you grasp the language better!  One thing I would mention however calling the clearInputBuf() cause a endless loop until you feed something into it, meaning if you call it when it is empty it won't move past the call even if the next call is printf() until you feed something into it..

Comment: @Programming_n00b: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All I hear is mixed arguments about how fflush() is undefined for the input stream

That's correct. Don't use `fflush()` to flush an input stream.

(A) will work for simple cases where you leave single character in the input stream (such as `scanf()` leaving a newline).

(B) Don't use. It's defined on some platforms. But don't rely on what standard calls *undefined behaviour*.

(C) Clearly the best out of the 3 options as it can "flush" any number of characters in the input stream.

But if you read *lines* (such as using `fgets()`), you'll probably have much less need to clear input streams.

Comment: Reading lines with `fgets()` still poses problems for overlong lines.

Comment: @chqrlie That's why I said "probably much less need" (using a sufficiently long buffer - which one can reasonably guess/control with the knowledge of inputs read) as opposed to, say, "no need".

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you think of as "flushing an input stream".

For output streams, the flush operation makes sure that all data that were written to the stream but were being kept buffered in memory have been flushed to the underlying filesystem file.  That's a very well defined operation.

For input streams, there is no well defined operation of what flushing the stream should do.  I would say that it does not make any sense.

Some implementations of the C standard library redefine the meaning of "flush" for input streams to mean "clear the rest of the current line which has not been read yet".  But that's entirely arbitrary, and other implementations choose to do nothing instead.

As of C11 this disparity has been corrected, and the standard now explicitly states that the `fflush()` function does not work with input streams, precisely because it makes no sense, and we do not want each runtime library vendor to go implementing it in whatever way they feel like.

So, please by all means do go ahead and implement your clearInputBuf() function the way you did, but do not think of it as "flushing the input stream".  There is no such thing.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to be platform dependent.

The `fflush()` cannot have an input stream as a parameter because according to the c standard, IT'S UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR since the behavior is not defined anywhere.

- On Windows, there is a defined behavior for `fflush()` and it does what you need it to do.
- On Linux, there is [`fpurge(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpurge.3.html) which does what you want it to do too.

The best way is to simply read all characters in a loop until

1. A newline character is found.
2. `EOF` is returned from `getchar()`.

like your `clearInputBuf()` function.

Note that flushing an output stream means writing all unwritten data to the stream, the data that is still in a buffer waiting to be flushed. But reading all the unread bytes from a stream, does not have the same meaning.

That's why it doesn't make sense to `fflush()` an input stream. On the other hand `fpurge()` is designed specifically for this, and it's name is a better choice because you want to clear the input stream and start fresh. The problem is, it's not a standard function.

Reading [`fpurge(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpurge.3.html) should clarify why `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, and why an implementation like the one on Windows doesn't make sense because it makes `fflush()` behave differently with different inputs. That's like making c compliant with PHP.

Comment: Nice to learn about `fpurge()`, yet it does not completely solve the problem: if there is more data available from the input file (ie: the terminal) that could fit in the `FILE` buffer, `fpurge()` will only discard what was read from the system, not what is still lingering in the system buffer for the terminal. The `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){}` solution seems more reliable.

Comment: @chqrlie Hence, the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is more subtile than it looks:

- On systems with elaborate terminal devices, such as unix and OS/X, input from the terminal is buffered at 2 separate levels: the system terminal uses a buffer to handle line editing, from just correcting input with backspace to full line editing with cursor and control keys.  This is called *cooked* mode. A full line of input is buffered in the system until the enter key is typed or the end-of-file key combination is entered.
- The `FILE` functions perform their own buffering, which is line buffered by default for streams associated with a terminal.  The buffer size in set to `BUFSIZ` by default and bytes are requested from the system when the buffered contents have been consumed. For most requests, a full line will be read from the system into the stream buffer, but in some cases such as when the buffer is full, only part of the line will have been read from the system when `scanf()` returns.  This is why discarding the contents of the stream buffer might not always suffice.

*Flushing* the input buffer may mean different things:

- discarding extra input, including the newline character, that have been entered by the user in response to input requests such as `getchar()`, `fgets()` or `scanf()`.  The need for *flushing* this input is especially obvious in the case of `scanf()` because most format lines will not cause the newline to be consumed.
- discarding any pending input and waiting for the user to hit a key.

You can implement a fluch function portably for the first case:

```
int flush_stream(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}
```

And this is exactly what your `clearInputBuf()` function does for `stdin`.

For the second case, there is no portable solution, and system specific methods are non trivial.