# C - Infinite loop after read a large decimal input from integer var

Tags: c

I am new to C. I am writing this do while loop but when I accidentally enter a decimal/double to the input, it will enter a infinite loop. Would you please correct me? Thank you!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int items;
   do {
        printf("Input item quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &items);
        if (items < 1 || items > 10)
            printf("ERROR: It must between 1 - 10.\n");
    } while (items < 1 || items > 10);
    return 0;
    
}
```

If I try to input 300.5, the output will become a loop

````
```
Input item quantity: ERROR: It must between 1 - 10.
Input item quantity: ERROR: It must between 1 - 10.
Input item quantity: ERROR: It must between 1 - 10.
```
````

Comment: In the future, always include a [mre] with debugging questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil dear sir, added #included <studio.h> and the int main (void) just now. Thank you

Comment: The simple answer is: don't bother.  `scanf` is not designed for robust user input with error recovery.  There are ways to flush the offending input if the user makes a mistake, but if this is just a toy program for learning, you can cheat and tell the user (you) to not make mistakes.  If you want to do robust input, it's far easier to [use something other than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).

Answer (score 3):

When `scanf` sees “.”, it stops scanning and leaves the “.” in the input stream. Your program receives 300 in `items`, for which it prints the message and loops. The next iteration of the loop calls `scanf` again. The “.” is still in the input stream, so `scanf` stops without changing `items` and returns zero to indicate it assigned zero items. Your program does not check the return result of `scanf`, so it fails to see this. It only checks the value of `items`, which has not changed.

Change the program to check the return value of `scanf` and to handle issues if the return value is not one, meaning that one item was assigned. To continue processing, you may need to use `getchar` or another input routine to read characters from the input until a new-line character is seen, marking the end of the line that the user typed.

Also, even if one item is assigned, you may wish to read the rest of the input line to see if the user entered any other notable characters, such as anything other than spaces. If they did, you may wish to report an error even if the assigned value is within range.

Comment: What do I have to do to escape the loop in the repeating "item" in this case which it ignores scanf forever? Do I need any break statement? Sorry I am really new to programming. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment about escaping the loop you might check out the following link:

[Clear scanf Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958298/is-this-the-proper-way-to-flush-the-c-input-stream)

Using that advice, I added a catch-all integer variable to your code.

```
int items, catchall; /* Added variable "catchall" */
```

Then, I enclosed your error message and added the code similar to the link to your program.

```
    if (items < 1 || items > 10)
    {
        printf("ERROR: It must between 1 - 10.\n");
        while ((catchall = getchar()) != '\n' && catchall != EOF) /* Clean up the buffer */
        {}
    }
```

That effectively clears out the "scanf" buffer so that your program can get out of the endless loop, and I did not see any undesired knock-on effects.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks you very much! It works like a charm!! Is the getchar() function call included in stdio.h? I don't know if I am allowed to put this in my code sicne it is just a beginner course, but it surely will help me in the future coding!