# Inaccurate size of string while dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c, string, data-structures, heap-memory

As per the image, you can see I have inserted whole lot of text but the total length by strlen is only showing 8 (k=8).[image]

I wanted to print full text inserted into one string a line but it is stopping in 8th character.

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    int i;
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    s = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
    int k=sizeof(strlen(s));
     for(i=0;i<sizeof(strlen(s)+1);i++)
    {
        if(*(s+i)!=' ')
            printf("%c",*(s+i));
        else
            printf("\n");
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: ```int k=sizeof(strlen(s))``` ----> What are you trying to do with this statement?

Comment: ```fflush(stdin)``` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `sizeof(strlen(s))` is the same as `sizeof(size_t)` -- it doesn't actually call strlen, just gives the size of its return type.

Comment: You don't actually use the incorrect `int k = sizeof(strlen(s));`. I suggest `int len = strlen(s);` move it up and use it instead of repeatedly calling `strlen(s)`.

Comment: Aside: it is more usual to write `*(s+i)` as `s[i]`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `realloc` ? It wont change `strlen(s)`

Comment: What purpose does ```k``` serve in your code?

Comment: What purpose does ```math.h``` serve?

Comment: The length of the string is  `int k=strlen(s);` : `sizeof` is for types only.

Comment: Yeah, I m stupid enough to end up there and I was confused for hours. This is actually a hacker rank question so Extention and realloc was there already ; why realloc was there I didn't get it either. Thank you very much it was actually the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the sizeof operator returns the size of the type in bytes, not the number of elements in the array. To get the number of elements in s, you should use strlen(s) instead.

Second, the scanf function will stop reading input when it encounters a newline character, so if you enter a string that is longer than 8 characters, it will only read the first 8 characters. To read a string that may contain spaces, you can use fgets instead:

```
fgets(s, 1024, stdin);
```

Finally, it's not necessary to call realloc after calling scanf or fgets, because the size of s is already 1024 characters, which is more than enough to hold the input string.

With these changes, your code should work as expected. Here's the modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char *s;
    s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    fgets(s, 1024, stdin);
    int k = strlen(s);
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if(*(s+i) != ' ') {
            printf("%c", *(s+i));
        } else {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof(strlen(s)+1)` is giving you the size of the `size_t` type (return type of `strlen` function) not the length of the string
2. `i` should have type `size_t`
3. fflush in the input stream is not needed and is strongly implementation-defined. Read:[Is this the proper way to flush the C input stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958298/is-this-the-proper-way-to-flush-the-c-input-stream)
4. You use `realloc` incorrectly. If it fails it will result in a memory leak. This `realloc` is not needed anyway. But you need to save the result in the temporary variable to not loose reference to the allocated memory.

```
char *tmp = realloc(s, strlen(s) + 1);
if(tmp) s = tmp
else { /* handle error */}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. It is really helpful but can you please explain me about size_t in this

Comment: @GhimireSuraj See [What is `size_t` in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)

Comment: `size_t` is the correct type to store the sizes. instead `int i;` => `size_t i;`